# VACUUMing DataBase in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, vacuum

[Here](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) it's mentioned that Vacuuming is necessary in Sqlite.

I have a Database (500MB) in my android application but after some insert and delete the size become 800MB but the database is exact as the first time.

I think Sqlite doesn't delete the empty rows.

I need to clean up the database without creating it again.

Is there any sql statement that I can use in android studio for clean up (**By programming**)

thank you

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053462/sqlite-vacuum-command

Comment: You linked to it. What is the problem?

Comment: **Morrison Chang**, There isn't any answer for the question that you put the link.
Instead of giving the negative point answer me.
.
**CL**: I want to codding in android.

Comment: You "think" it doesn't delete empty rows? That is easily checkable by using the DDMS tools or a SQLite database browser program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone already said you linked to it. You asked this...

> Is there any sql statement

The doc you linked to contains a link to this...

http://sqlite.org/syntax/vacuum-stmt.html

The vacuum command is a statement. That means you would call it the same way you would a select statement.